# scanf() when trying to enter a string with or without whitespace closes the program

Tags: c

When trying to enter `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &answer);` the program hangs for a second and then closes, what can I do to fix this.

I have tried with and without the `&`, with differing ways of taking in whitespace and in different places. This did work before I included the array `*aarray[]` and had the while loop inside of the switch statement, (in the full code there are multiple cases with different questions and I didn't want to create a while loop in each one.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void trivia();
int randomquestion();
void main() 
{
  trivia();
}
int randomquestion()
{
    int g;
    g = rand() % 29;
    if(g%2 == 0)
    {
        return g;
    }
    else
    {
        return --g;
    }
}
void trivia(void) {
void *answer;
char *aarray[] = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
const char *history[] = { "Which English king was \"mad\"?","George III",
                        "Who started the Protestant Reformation?","Martin Luther",
                        "Who was the first person to see the moons of Jupiter?","Galileo",
                        "What Viking group settled in France before conquering England, Sicily, and Malta?","The Normans",
                        "What group sacked Baghdad in 1258, ending the Islamic Golden Age?","The Mongols",
                        "Against what city did Rome fight the Punic Wars?","Carthage",
                        "What yellow gas was famously used in WWI?","Mustard Gas",
                        "What epic poem is thought to be the oldest in the English language?","Beowulf",
                        "What ancient empire was led by Xerxes, Cyrus, and Darius?","Persia",
                        "Who was the most notorious member of the Ba'ath Party?","Saddam Hussein",
                        "What Italian adventurer wrote about his 24 year journey from Venice to China and back?","Marco Polo",
                        "What young pharaoh's tomb was discovered in 1922?","Tutankhamun",
                        "Before becoming king of England, what country was James I the king of?","Scotland",
                        "What was the primary language of the Byzantine Empire?","Greek",
                        "For what crime was Al Capone convicted of in 1931?","Tax Evasion"
                        };
char y;
int a, g, i = 0, points = 0;
printf("This is a trivia game, choose from History (H), Geography (G), Sport (S) or Technology (T) \n");
printf("There will be 5 random questions, and the user will have to enter the correct answer.\n");
printf("Please enter the letter of your choice. \n");
scanf(" %c", &y);
switch(y){
    case 'H' :
        for(a=0; a<29; a++)
        {
            aarray[a] = history[a];
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("That was an incorrect input. \n");
        trivia();
}
while ( i <5)
{
    g = randomquestion();
    printf("\n%s :", aarray[g]);
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", answer);
    printf("\nYour answer is %s", answer);
    if(strcmp(aarray[++g],answer) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nCorrect!");
                ++points;

            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nIncorrect, the answer was %s.", aarray[g]);
            }
    i++;
}
}
```

I expect it to take the input and then carry on through the while loop.

Comment: No [mcve] *again* ?

Comment: How is this not that, what would I need to add to make it work?

Comment: Where is `main`?

Comment: A [mcve] is something we can copy/paste/compile without guesswork.

Comment: I have hallucinations or it's still the case `void * answer; ... scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", &answer)` ? ^^

Comment: Please avoid "magic" numbers such as `29`.

Comment: minor: `return --g;` is pointless. `return g-1;` will do the same without unneeded side-effects.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it compilable now?

Comment: Why are you asking me? Try it yourself... From what I *see* it is not.

Comment: @WeatherVane magic numbers?

Comment: @Seabright22 where are your `#include`s?

Comment: @Seabright22 If you are asked to add  a MCVE, please produce one. Do not just add things without actually compiling your code.

Comment: That magic number `29` occurs at least twice in the code so that makes it hard to maintain (and to understand its meaning). Also if it is meant to be the number of elements in the arrays, that is `30` not `29` and is better derived from `sizeof(history) / sizeof(*history)`.

Comment: @Seabright22 `answer` is a pointer.  What value does that pointer have when it is given to `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", answer);`?  As code does not assign that pointer anything before the `scanf()` call, `scanf()` is given garbage.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` are missing.

Comment: @Seabright22, Who or what text suggested `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", answer);`?  It is not much different than `gets()`.  Both are prone to overflow.

Comment: @Seabright22 What compiler are you using? What settings? With `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", answer);` I get "warning: 'answer' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]".

Comment: @chux stackoverflow suggested that when I was looking for how to take a string with whitespace, and I am using GNU GCC with default settings

Comment: I apologise if I seem a bit stupid with C, this is the first program I have made in this language and it is more complicated than the other ones I am used to

Comment: @Seabright22 Hint: start with some real simple programs first and don't forget to read your C text book

Comment: @Seabright22 Try using `gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0...` to see for yourself more issues.  C assumes you know how to code and does not carry a lot of baggage in its emitted code - that what makes it so fast and not easy for learners.  Welcome to coding without [training wheels](https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_dd5016e2-b6d3-4adc-a5b4-bb8821b1154e?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg).

Comment: This was my first assignment, I can code decently in Python so the change from that to C seemed like a stepdown in functionality but I can see the use of it a lot more when tied to assembly and stuff, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", answer);` is trying to write a string to an uninitialized, unallocated (and more importantly) *incomplete* pointer of type `void *`.

You need to declare it as a complete type (i.e. `char *`) and allocate memory for it, either on the stack by explicitly declaring array size `[LEN]` or dynamically with `malloc(LEN)` and later `free` it.